# Salvar imagem na pasta da aplicação(File upload) usando EJB+Servlet JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, ejb

Pessoal boas? Preciso de um exemplo de como fazer o file upload usando as tecnologias, EJB+Servlet+JSP... estou trabalhando num projecto que preciso inserir as imagens dinamicamente na minha aplicação. 
Abraços!

Comment: Banguela, dê uma olhada [nesse exemplo do BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/664577) usando um Servlet + [Multipart Config](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html).

Comment: Estou ver mano... depois comunico!

Comment: Já implementaste? Olha vou testar mais tarde ainda vou para Universidade... qualquer coisa eu comunico ilustre!